Why is test that passes on second run showing up as a failing test instead of Flakey when using surefire maven?
I have the following results from a test
[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [INFO] Results:

[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [INFO] 

[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [ERROR] Failures: 

[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [ERROR] ....WebServiceProxySubTest.testCallbackWithApplicationRefreshException

[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [ERROR]   Run 1: WebServiceProxySubTest.testCallbackWithApplicationRefreshException:309 expected null, but was:<{WS_NAME=gws#echo}>

[2024-09-20T14:25:00.929Z] [INFO]   Run 2: PASS
...
[2024-09-20T14:23:47.360Z] [ERROR] Tests run: 74, Failures: 7, Errors: 6, Skipped: 2



The problem here is that instead of the second run allowing the whole test to pass even though the first one failed. The test is still seen as a failure. I can't find anything in the docs for how to tell the surefire plugin that it is ok so where do I configure that.
